# cv2.imwrite error when looping over images

Tags: python, opencv

I am experiencing an error when i am looping over images that are stored in a folder. Overall, what i want to accomplish, is to extract the mouth feature from a series of images using the respective haar classifier, i.e. crop the image and store its mouth only.
The thing is that after the very first iteration, i keep getting the !img_empty() error, despite there being 40 more images to process (for now). The following is the functions code:

```
def lip_extraction():
    path = "./data/test_cut-opencv/"
    os.chdir(path)
    images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("*.png")]
    print(images)
    i=0
    for image in images:
    # print(len(images))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        print(len(gray))
        faces = face_casecade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        
        print(i)
        cv2.imwrite("img_1.png", gray)
        i+=1
```

`i` is a variable for checking the loop.

The following error is thrown:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

Any pointers or solution? I am already doing my imports correctly, so that's not it. The code works only once when i introduce a "break" statement in the second for loop after "gray" is altered/sliced. Otherwise, it saves no output at all.

I tried using different paths and different ways to access those paths till no avail. Running the code above shows that the images array is initialized correctly, i.e. it reads all images. After that though, it says `!img_empty()` as an error.

Comment: use a loop and print the image name you're about to load instead of using a comprehension. You probably have a corrupt/empty image file

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error in `imread` but in `imwrite` (according to your own error message. And to your own description: you need to put a `break` just before the `imwrite` to avoid the error).

And the error is quite explicit: you can't `imwrite` an empty array.
And since what you write is `gray`, conclusion is obvious: `gray` is an empty array.

Which is not surprising. Because, I don't know exactly what you are doing, but I surmise that `faces` is an array of bounding box of different faces that are found in an image.

So if you have a 300x300 image with 2 faces in it, one at position (10,10) with size (50×50), and another at position (100,20) with size (50×80) (a long face — edit: a large one, rather. since it is H×W images, not W×H :D), then your code will do

```
# gray is a 300×300 image
gray=gray[10:60,10:60]
# Now gray is is 50×50 image
gray=gray[100:150,20:100]
# Now gray is an empty array since there are no lines 100:150 in a 50×50 image
```

If you are trying to save image of individual faces, I think what you want to do is, instead of

```
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        
        print(i)
        cv2.imwrite("img_1.png", gray)
        i+=1
```

more something like

```
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            towrite = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]     
            print(i)
            cv2.imwrite(f"img_{i}.png", towrite)
            i+=1
```

Comment: That seemed like it was it! I was following this tutorial, and they had apparently done something like that. Thanks for your help!